# Exchange 2013 - Calendar won't migrate?

Tags: public-folders, exchange-2013

I'm finishing up an Exchange 2013 migration. All mailboxes have been moved, and everything is peachy. I'm trying to migrate the Public folders, but I have a calendar that refuses to migrate due to an error.

```
Property Expression "Vacation Calendar" isn't valid
```

I got this error on some of the public folders due to spaces in the alias, and replacing spaces with underscores fixed those errors. I renamed the calendar itself but that hasn't corrected the error, and no alias field exists AFAIK for public calendars. The calendar appears as "Vacation_Calendar" in every field I have modified, but the error message still shows it containing a space.

I also tried searching through the PF database with no luck, and also renaming the AD object that corresponds to the calendar. Still no dice. Is this hidden somewhere??

Has anyone dealt with this particular issue before, and if so what is the solution?

Comment: Problem solved...Using ADSIedit find the calendar exchange system object, and remove spaces from the mailNickName field.

Comment: + 1 Good deal, please post it as the actual answer to your own question (with details or screenshots if possible) and accept it.  This could help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposted as an answer...didn't realize I could answer my own with low rep.

Problem solved...Using ADSIedit find the calendar exchange system object, and remove spaces from the mailNickName field.

[image]